# Escape SQL function string parameter within query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL view that calls a scalar function with a string parameter. The problem is that the string occasionally has special characters which causes the function to fail.

The view query looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
  Id, Name, StartDate, EndDate
  ,dbo.[fnGetRelatedInfo] (Name) as Information
FROM dbo.Session
```

The function looks like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetRelatedInfo]( @Name varchar(50) )
RETURNS varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result varchar(200)

    SELECT @Result = ''

    SELECT @Result = @Result + Info + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) 
    FROM [SessionInfo] 
    WHERE SessionName = @Name 

    RETURN @Result
END
```

How do I escape the name value so it will work when passed to the function?

Comment: what are the special characters? what is the error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the problem is non-unicode characters in `dbo.Session.Name`. Since the parameter to the function is `VARCHAR`, it will only hold unicode characters, so the non-unicode characters are lost when being passed to the function. The solution for this would be to change the parameter to be `NVARCHAR(50)`.

However, if you care about performance, and more importantly consistent, reliable results stop using this function immediately. Alter your view to simply be:

```
SELECT  s.ID,
        s.Name,
        s.StartDate,
        s.EndDate,
        (   SELECT  si.Info + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) 
            FROM    SessionInfo AS si
            WHERE   si.SessionName = s.Name
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Information
FROM    dbo.Session AS s;
```

Using variable concatenation can lead to unexpected results which are dependent on the internal pathways of the execution plan. So I would rule this out as a solution immediately. Not only this, the RBAR nature of a scalar UDF means that this will not scale well at all.

Various ways of doing this grouped concatenation have been [benchmarked here](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation), where CLR is actually the winner, but this is not always an option.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation. I took your advice and removed the function.